# Client Authentication using SSL without any client side code implementation

Tags: ssl, authentication

I am working on the Java web service and using Tomcat server. Since this application would be B2B, so we require Client Authentication. We are using openssl for creating a certificate. For each user we will create a self signed certificate and we will send it through mail or something. Now here problem comes, when client make a call to server over a secured connection, client should send the certificate provided by server.  I want that client can send the certificate for client authentication, without any code implementation on client side. Is there any way to achieve this? Can someone tell me the exact steps required to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For each user we will create a self signed certificate and we will
>   send it through mail or something.

Stop right there. This is already insecure. It implies that you have the user's private key. The user, and only the user, should have the user's private key. The user should generate his own private key and if you insist his own self-signed certificate, or better still get it signed by a CA. He should then send it to *you* if you need it for any reason.

What you are doing is completely back to front and from the legal/security point of view utterly worthless. In fact it contains major legal *risks* that you need to inform yourself about before proceeding any further. One of those is complete loss of non-repudiation of user transactions. This is enough to shut down your business.

Comment: It is our requirement that our own CA( Who is not the certified CA) will sign the certificate, and that certificate we will send to the client side. Now for client authentication, either we need to add client certificate to the truststore at server side or the client will send some details like public key, which only client can send and server side can verify. I dont know what I should do without creating a legal risk. But one thing is sure that I have to verify the user on the basis of certificate details what the server has provided.

Comment: @user1367714 If you are acting as the CA in the case you certainly shouldn't be generating self-signed certificates. You should generate a CA certificate for your CA, either get it signed by a CA or import it into your server truststore, and sign client CSRs with that certificate. Then all you have to do is set your server to require client authentication. If the client has his private key and his signed certificate in his keystore (Java) or the corresponding OpenSSL or whatever setup, it will all work seamlessly and automatically during the SSL handshake.

Comment: ohh ok! Last doubt. For connection with client, we have a Certificate for server which would be verified by a CA(like Verisign, Entrust). Now for Client our on CA will sign the certificate. The whole idea behind creating a client certificate on server side and then sending a certificate was that we were not planning to provide a interface to client to generate a client certificate. As our application is a WebService, so we dont want any client side implementation(which can be avoided). Now if we go by your suggestion, that our CA will sign the client CSRs.

Comment: Then if we set Cient Authentication to true in Tomcat server. Will the SSL handshake will automatically take place? As here we have two certificates involved(One for server which is provided by certified CA, and one is client certificate which is certified by our CA). Now  I am confused how the details for client authentication will come to the server side and how will server verify those details?

Comment: @user1367714 If ypu set Tomcat to require client authentication, it will ask for the client's certificate during the SSL handshake, and fail the connection attempt if the certificate isn't provided or isn't trusted.